# javax.json.bind-api vs. jakarta.json.bind-api

Tags: jsonb, yasson

What is the difference between the two packages of the same json-b spec? Why Yasson uses the Jarkata version rather than the javax one?

If I include the javax version as compile-scope dependency and Yasson as runtime-scope,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
            <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

then, using JDK 11, I get ClassCastException at runtime:

> Jsonb JSON Binding provider org.eclipse.yasson.JsonBindingProvider
> could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> org.eclipse.yasson.JsonBindingProvider cannot be cast to class
> javax.json.bind.spi.JsonbProvider
> (org.eclipse.yasson.JsonBindingProvider and
> javax.json.bind.spi.JsonbProvider are in unnamed module of loader
> 'app')

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question after googling...

The "EE" stack is now owned by Eclipse rather than Oracle. As such,

> the Eclipse Foundation can't create any new Java packages using the javax namespace, but it can create new classes and subclasses under the existing ones.

I guess that's the reason for repackaging the Oracle-owned "javax" namespace into "jakarta".

Link to the info source article: https://www.baeldung.com/java-enterprise-evolution